# How to draw lines around a specific value in an array

Tags: python, numpy, visualization, scikit-image

I am using a sample image that can be found [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=images+with+regions+that+are+out+of+focus+and+blurry&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiLxuGthtj8AhUqAzQIHQrwBoUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=images+with+regions+that+are+out+of+focus+and+blurry&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1DGAliyE2CUFWgAcAB4AIABQ4gBmwWSAQIxMpgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=HYjLY8vDL6qG0PEPiuCbqAg&bih=796&biw=1440#imgrc=j1SsmU0-5pCJYM) to test out how to find regions that are blurry in an image. I tried out entropy method [link](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/filters/plot_entropy.html) and this is what I get (see image below). I included this preamble and links so that the problem is reproducible.

[image]

In the 'entropy image' array, the parts (i.e the dark parts) that are classed as 'blurry' are set to 0 and these parts are the blue parts in the 'entropy image mask'.

I am essentially trying to use this information (i.e the location of the predicted blurry parts) to draw lines (or overlay the images) that indicate these blurry areas on the 'input image'.

My code looked something like:

```
import numpy as np

zero_indices = np.where(entropy_image_array == 0)

input_image_array[zero_indices[0], zero_indices[1], 1] = 1
```

However, I am not getting the desired result. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Run an edge detection filter on the mask then overlay the results on the original image.

Comment: Entropy as defined in the function you use is not useful for distinguishing blurry and sharp parts.

Comment: @CrisLuengo is there some other method that you suggest I should try?

Comment: invert the question. assess focus at different scales. laplacian pyramid or fourier transform. Q&A for that exists. don't send us to a google search page for input data.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have no idea why you're getting fiesty with me. My question was how to overlay the image and that has been answered by @ ouroborus. I did what they suggested and got my desired result.

Comment: ah! so you truly just asked how to draw some lines over a picture? assessing focus/blurriness was not the question? then I misinterpreted this question. in my perception, your first comment response did not steer the discussion towards drawing lines. in fact, you asked for details on alternatives for "entropy", rather than how to "overlay". feel free to clarify the question by [edit]ing it. I regret that I changed your question's title. I did not believe that drawing lines was really an issue. where do you attempt to draw lines? perhaps a [mre] would help...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I know this forum is for coding questions so I tried to stay on topic by asking how to draw the lines because it's a good way to visualise the accuracy of my solution to another problem (finding blurry regions). When someone else chipped in about that, I thought it wouldn't harm to reply. I honestly didn't know how else to make a minimal reproducible example that's why I included those links (and I said that). I don't know how to create a NumPy array that'll display a blurry image... But anyway, it's all good my question has actually been answered and I upvoted the comment.